# Linking a shared library from a large github project

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, parquet

I'm trying to use the following github project https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp. I was able to build it and the .so files are available in parquet-cpp/build/latest. I copied the .so files(both of libparquet as well as libarrow which had been built) in a separate directory and wrote a simple hello world, simply importing the library as:

```
#include <arrow/io/file.h>
#include <parquet/api/reader.h>
#include <parquet/api/writer.h>
```

Now I ran

```
g++ -Wall test.cpp  -L. -lparquet -larrow
```

However this throws an error as unable to find .h files of arrow/parquet. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the path for the header files in the compilation instruction. You need to find directory containing `parquet/api/reader.h` and include it in the compilation command

```
g++ -Wall -I path_containing_header test.cpp  -L. -lparquet -larrow
```

You may include several directories with multiple `-I` instruction.

Comment: I tried this: g++ -Wall -I /home/saatvik/parquet-cpp/arrow_ep/src/arrow_ep-install/include -I /home/saatvik/parquet-cpp/src/ t2.cpp  -L. -lparquet -larrow - But I think I'm using some wrong path - The earlier error has gone, but now theres a huge host of errors being thrown.

Comment: When I include the examples from https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp/tree/master/examples, I get errors as: /tmp/ccCqlpoH.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xc4d): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnWriter<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)0> >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, bool const*)'
test.cpp:(.text+0xcb6): undefined reference to `parquet::TypedColumnWriter<parquet::DataType<(parquet::Type::type)1> >::WriteBatch(long, short const*, short const*, int const*)'... again a long list of such undefined reference errors